# How to block some bots in .htaccess but except access robots.txt?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, virtualhost, robots.txt

I've blocked some bad bots using .htaccess.

For example:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^bot1" bots
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^bot2" bots
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^bot3" bots
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bots
Deny from 111.222.333.444
Deny from 555.666.777.888
Deny from 999.000.111.222
</Limit>
```

I also blocked them in robots.txt, but I saw on the error_log that they couldn't access robots.txt too:

```
[client 111.222.333.444] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/robots.txt
```

If some of them respect the rules of robots.txt and then stop visiting, the server can avoid some unnecessary responses. Is this a good idea?

How to block them in .htaccess but except access robots.txt?

---

After referring to the suggestions of @djdomi and @MrWhite, I made the following changes in .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^bot1" bots
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^bot2" bots
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^bot3" bots    
<RequireAll>
  Require all granted
  Require not env bots
  Require not ip 111.222.333.444
  Require not ip 555.666.777.888
  Require not ip 999.000.111.222
</RequireAll>
<Files "robots.txt">
  Require all granted
</Files>
```

Is this working? Does the order matter for `<RequireAll>` and `<Files>`?
I have not tested further, only know that the website access is normal without any server errors so far.

Comment: I think you have to allow in a extra part robots.txt for everyone. since you are not showing us the configuration and environment to reproduce it, it's just a guess

Comment: Thanks. How to allow in a extra part robots.txt for everyone? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: <Files "robots.txt">Require all granted</Files>

Comment: How to do it with .htaccess?

Comment: Dear usr12, I noticed that you are asking some questions about specific end-user topics that are off-topic for this discussion. Could you please explain why you prefer to use htaccess instead of the configuration file? The process for configuring both is essentially the same, but I just want to make sure I understand your reasons for using htaccess specifically. Thank you.

Comment: "`<Files "robots.txt">Require all granted</Files>`" - Although you shouldn't mix the newer Apache 2.4 auth directives with the (deprecated) Apache 2.2 (`Order`, `Allow`, `Deny`) directives as in the question - you can get unexpected results. (The OP should be using Apache 2.4 `Require` directives throughout.) @djdomi

Comment: it was written out of my knowledge, but problem by my side is, I am using nginx for a while where it is much easier ;)

Comment: maybe i did not got the point of mrwhite, but [apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) says I may be right - and OP flagged "apache 2.4" in the flags so I assume and if I understood correctly, that my example should be the right behavior.

Comment: @MrWhite what do you think of the change?

Comment: Dear @djdomi, I don't want to restart the Apache again and again in a production environment. Also, put the related settings in the same file for better management.

Comment: @djdomi "maybe i did not got the point of mrwhite, but apache doc says I may be right" - Yes, but my point was, you had suggested an Apache 2.4 directive (and yes, the question is tagged "apache-2.4"), but the OP (at least initially) was actually using "old" Apache 2.2 directives. And, as [stated in the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) you should not mix  "old" and "new" auth directives in the same context. (Counter intuitively, the "old" auth directives can _override_ the new directives, causing unexpected results.)

Comment: @usr12 "what do you think of the change?" - Yes, that looks OK - now using all Apache 2.4 directives. Please test it (it's still possible there might be other conflicts on your system) and put it as an "answer" in the box below (to help other readers etc.) if it's all working as expected (you can then later "accept" it). :) `<Files>` containers are processed _later_, so I'm not sure that the order strictly matters, but it is certainly more logical to have the `<Files>` container later (as you have).